# Testing sign in functionality with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to unit test a React SignIn component (with React Testing Library and Jest) for two pieces of functionality: 1) successful sign in, and 2) unsuccessful sign in (email could not be found) which renders an error message.  However, the mock function doesn't appear to ever be called, and I'm stuck as a result and I can't figure out where my problem lies.  I'm assuming I'm either setting up the mock function incorrectly, but I can't say for sure.  I've tried setting up the mock function several different ways but receive the same error.  As you'll see in my test file, I expect the mock function to be called once when the form is submitted by clicking the 'Sign in' button, but it's never called.

The `SignIn` component is structured as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/client"

const SignIn = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")

  // This function calls the signIn function from next-auth/client
  const validateEmail = async () => {
    await signIn("email", { email })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <Logo />
        <Form onSubmit={validateEmail}>
          <div>
            <Email
              name="email"
              label="Email"
              testKey="email"
              afterChange={(e) => {
                setEmail(e.target.value)
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </Form>
        <div className="sign-up">
          Don{"'"}t have an account? <Link href="/sign-up">Sign up.</Link>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignIn
```

The Form component, a child of the SignIn component, accepts `validateEmail` as props and is ultimately used in a helper function that validates and cleans up the data before calling the signIn function, as seen below.

```
const Form = ({ validateEmail }) => {
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // Does some validation, formatting, etc.
    await validateEmail(event)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {children}
        {onSubmit && (
          <Button type="submit">
            Sign in
          </Button>
        )}
    </form>
  )
}

export default Form
```

I'm trying to unit test the `SignIn` component and want to mock the signIn function that I'm importing from "next-auth/client".  But when I click the Sign in button and submit the form, it doesn't look like the function is being called, and I can't quite figure out why.  My test looks like this:

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom"
import { configure, fireEvent, render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react"
import user from "@testing-library/user-event"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/client"
import React from "react"
import SignIn from "../../pages/auth/sign-in"

jest.mock("next-auth/client", () => {
  return {
    signIn: () => { ok: true }
  }
})

test("signs in successfully", async () => {
  const validEmail = "validemail@test.com"
  const authConfig = { callbackUrl: undefined, redirect: false }

  const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<SignIn />)
  const emailInput = getByTestId(/email/i)
  const signInButton = getByText(/sign in/i)

  user.type(emailInput, validEmail)
  fireEvent.click(signInButton)

  expect(signIn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // Is called 0 times and test fails
})
```

As always, any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to put the expect inside a waitFor, or maybe await? As your function is async: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/

Comment: @Nacho same result unfortunately.

Comment: And did you verify that the button is being rendered?? a it is in a conditional statement

Comment: @Nacho yup!  If I remove the actual assertions and run the test, it passes.  If I remember correctly, in this scenario, the test would fail if the component doesn't render

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually mocking the `signIn` function, just use Jest's automock instead.

```
jest.mock("next-auth/client")
```

This way Jest will automatically mock all functions from `next-auth/client` for you.

The reason why it doesn't work in your case is because you're overriding the Jest mock with an explicit function. The `signIn` variable will actually be the function you passed, i.e. `() => { ok: true }`, and not a Jest mock instance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to perform a mock over Next Auth.

First of all you need a Next Auth React mocked version, you can do something like this

```
 import * as nextAuthReact from 'next-auth/react';

 jest.mock('next-auth/react');
 const nextAuthReactMocked = nextAuthReact as jest.Mocked<typeof nextAuthReact>;
```

then you can start making you own test overriding Next Auth React methods

```
describe('Test Auth component', () => {
  it('Shows Home page and auth component', async () => {
    nextAuthReactMocked.useSession.mockImplementation(
      (_options?: UseSessionOptions<boolean> | undefined) => {
        return { data: null, status: 'loading' };
      }
    );

    nextAuthReactMocked.signIn.mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ error: '', status: 403, ok: false, url: '' })
    );

    const { getAllByText } = render(
      <Auth>
        <Home />
      </Auth>
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
      const welcomeTitle = getAllByText('Welcome text');
      expect(welcomeTitle);
    });
  });
});
```

This is an example test when we are not logged, in my case we have a condition when we are not logged shows a welcome text or shows a component when we are logged.